# Symfony Doctrine method 'getManager' not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

As far as I know from the documentation if `use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;` is extended Etity Manager should be available in Controller. But for unknown reason this doesn't work for me:

```
namespace Park\PurchaseBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class PurchaseController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    }
}
```

Symfony's app_dev displays error

`Attempted to call an undefined method named "getManager" of class "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry".
Did you mean to call e.g. "getManagerForClass", "getManagerNames", "getManagers" or "resetManager"?`

App_Kernel.php looks ok

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            ...
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        );

        ...
        return $bundles;
    }
}
```

What is the something important that I may missed?

**EDIT**

It's an old project made by someone who I didn't know. It made on Symfony v2.1 and now I'm trying to upgrade it to v2.7. I've updated composer.json and completed `composer update` without any warnings. Now when using `$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()` instead of `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` server crashes with blank screen from Symfony debug app. Here is Apache output to error.log file:

```
[Mon Sep 19 18:15:16.821608 2016] [:error] [pid 16040] [client 192.168.100.8:36756] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://192.168.100.8/park/app_dev.php/admin/users
[Mon Sep 19 18:15:16.821614 2016] [:error] [pid 16040] [client 192.168.100.8:36756] PHP   1. {main}() /home/user/www/park/web/app_dev.php:0, referer: http://192.168.100.8/park/app_dev.php/admin/users
[Mon Sep 19 18:15:16.821619 2016] [:error] [pid 16040] [client 192.168.100.8:36756] PHP   2. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel->handle() /home/user/www/park/web/app_dev.php:34, referer: http://192.168.100.8/park/app_dev.php/admin/users
[Mon Sep 19 18:15:16.821626 2016] [:error] [pid 16040] [client 192.168.100.8:36756] PHP   3. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle() /home/user/www/park/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2480, referer: http://192.168.100.8/park/app_dev.php/admin/users
[Mon Sep 19 18:15:16.821632 2016] [:error] [pid 16040] [client 192.168.100.8:36756] PHP   4. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handle() /home/user/www/park/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3269, referer: http://192.168.100.8/park/app_dev.php/admin/users
[Mon Sep 19 18:15:16.821638 2016] [:error] [pid 16040] [client 192.168.100.8:36756] PHP   5. Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handleRaw() /home/user/www/park/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3115, referer: http://192.168.100.8/park/app_dev.php/admin/users
[Mon Sep 19 18:15:16.821644 2016] [:error] [pid 16040] [client 192.168.100.8:36756] PHP   6. call_user_func_array:{/home/user/www/park/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3156}() /home/user/www/park/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3156, referer: http://192.168.100.8/park/app_dev.php/admin/users
[Mon Sep 19 18:15:16.821650 2016] [:error] [pid 16040] [client 192.168.100.8:36756] PHP   7. Mediapark\\UserBundle\\Controller\\UserController->editAction() /home/user/www/park/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3156, referer: http://192.168.100.8/park/app_dev.php/admin/users
[Mon Sep 19 18:15:16.821657 2016] [:error] [pid 16040] [client 192.168.100.8:36756] PHP   8. Doctrine\\Bundle\\DoctrineBundle\\Registry->getEntityManager() /home/user/www/park/src/Mediapark/UserBundle/Controller/UserController.php:54, referer: http://192.168.100.8/park/app_dev.php/admin/users
[Mon Sep 19 18:15:16.821677 2016] [:error] [pid 16040] [client 192.168.100.8:36756] PHP   9. Doctrine\\Bundle\\DoctrineBundle\\Registry->getEntityManager() /home/user/www/park/app/cache/dev/classes.php:7635, referer: http://192.168.100.8/park/app_dev.php/admin/users
[Mon Sep 19 18:15:16.821685 2016] [:error] [pid 16040] [client 192.168.100.8:36756] PHP  10. Doctrine\\Bundle\\DoctrineBundle\\Registry->getEntityManager() /home/user/www/park/app/cache/dev/classes.php:7635, referer: http://192.168.100.8/park/app_dev.php/admin/users
[Mon Sep 19 18:15:16.821693 2016] [:error] [pid 16040] [client 192.168.100.8:36756] PHP  11. Doctrine\\Bundle\\DoctrineBundle\\Registry->getEntityManager() /home/user/www/park/app/cache/dev/classes.php:7635, referer: http://192.168.100.8/park/app_dev.php/admin/users
...
```

And here composer.json require section:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "Trsteel/ckeditor-bundle": "~1.6",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
    "symfony/intl": "2.8.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.6.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.8.*",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "<=2.3.x-dev",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "1.1.0",
    "behat/mink-extension": "1.2.0",
    "behat/mink-browserkit-driver":  "1.1.0",
    "behat/mink-zombie-driver":  "1.1.0",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.4",
    "hipchat/hipchat-php": "dev-master",
    "inori/banklink" : "0.2.4",
    "exercise/htmlpurifier-bundle": "*"
},
```

Comment: Interesting.  Sure looks like it should work.  Did you by any chance manually update your composer.json file?  Is it possible that you have an older version of Doctrine?  Does $em->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'); work?

Comment: Looks like you have an old version of Symfony. You can try `$this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();`

Comment: I've updated the question. getEntityManager() and get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager') crashes Apache completely.

Comment: The plot thickens.  Going from 2.1 to 2.7 is quite a leap.  Lots of BC breaks between 2.1 and 2.3.  Might try going to 2.3 first.  Otherwise, create a fresh 2.7 project then copy your legacy app over bit by bit just to get something working.  Consider jumping right to 3.1.  Probably be about the same amount of work.  Good luck.